# Area type plotting with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I want to make a kind of area plot, a difference between two datasets, with logarithmic Y scale. Is it possible with option 'stack plot'?. In the example provided in the manual, of course the default base level is 0. First of all, it is not really good in log mode, second, that I actually would make one of the plots the baseline. Any idea?

My goal is to make something like this:
[image]

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}               
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ymin=1e-5, ymax=1e-3,
%       ymode=log,
stack plots=y,
area style,
enlarge x limits=false]
\addplot coordinates
{(1,3.121e-5) (2,2.882e-5) (3,1.469e-4) (4,3.910e-5) (5,3.910e-5)
(6,1.220e-4)}
\closedcycle;
\addplot coordinates
{(1,3.121e-5) (2,2.882e-5) (3,1.469e-4) (4,3.910e-5) (5,3.910e-5)
(6,1.220e-4)}
\closedcycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please rephrase this: "First of all, it is not really good in log mode, second, that I actually would make one of the plots the baseline. Any idea?" I am not good in English but I don't think that the phrase as it is makes sense...

Comment: Not sure, but if you mean that you want one of the plots to be the baseline, then the suggested way is to plot the difference of the values...

Comment: Well, I think you are right in that I omitted a 'to be' (or not to be :) ). Concerning your suggestion: I want to display both values, not only their difference.

Comment: If you plot the "baseline plot" ... How can it be a baseline then? Do you want just to subtract it's mean value from the total diagram? (I can not imagine another way for the one of the plots to be printed and be the baseline too)

Comment: So you want to fill the area between two plots? Look at the `fillbetween` library, it's described in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## new answer

My first answer was too quick, i.e. there is no bug in PGFPlots when stacked plots are used, so here my revised answer:

The key is to know/remember, that when stacked plots are used, that the given commands are evaluated in *reversed* order. So it is important to state `\addplot fill between` *before* the `\addplot` commands where the paths are named.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=1e-5,
        ymax=1e-3,
        ymode=log,
        stack plots=y,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        no markers,
    ]
        % because when "stacked" plots is used the commands are evaluated in
        % reversed order, we need to place the `fill between' command *before*
        % the corresponding named pathes!
        \addplot [fill=green!20] fill between [of=A and B];

        \addplot+ [very thick,name path=A] coordinates {
            (1,3.121e-5) (2,2.882e-5) (3,1.469e-4)
            (4,3.910e-5) (5,3.910e-5) (6,1.220e-4)
        };
        \addplot+ [very thick,name path=B] coordinates {
            (1,3.121e-5) (2,2.882e-5) (3,1.469e-4)
            (4,3.910e-5) (5,3.910e-5) (6,1.220e-4)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

---

## old answer

As Torbjørn T. already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412222/area-type-plotting-with-pgfplot#comment1029092_412222) (normally) the `fillbetween` library would be the choice to solve your request, but currently there seems to be a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/200/) in that library when it is used together with stacked plots. So we have to find another way to solve your problem.

Why your approach using `\closedcycle` isn't working as well is explained in the comments of my code as well.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=1e-5,
        ymax=1e-3,
        ymode=log,
        stack plots=y,
        area style,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        % so the axis lines are on the top of the "cycle" lines
        axis on top,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1,3.121e-5) (2,2.882e-5) (3,1.469e-4)
            (4,3.910e-5) (5,3.910e-5) (6,1.220e-4)
        }
            % `\closedcycle' doesn't work here, because it would it cycles to
            % zero, which is *above* the lines here. So we have to create this
            % path by hand.
            % `current plot begin' refers to the first coordinate and because
            % we are in a logarithmic axis `/pgfplots/ymin' yields the (natural)
            % logarithmic value. (This is around -11 in this case and thus would
            % again be above the plot.) So we have to delogarithmize it.
            |- (current plot begin |- {axis cs:0,e^(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})})
        ;
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1,3.121e-5) (2,2.882e-5) (3,1.469e-4)
            (4,3.910e-5) (5,3.910e-5) (6,1.220e-4)
        }
            |- (current plot begin |- {axis cs:0,e^(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})})
        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]